# PayPal API not connecting (not giving an error)

Tags: laravel, paypal

I'm using the `srmklive/paypal` PayPal package for Laravel. Sandbox is working fine, but the issues arrive when I'm trying to switch it to live.

I've given the following credentials from the `developer.paypal.com` dashboard:

- PAYPAL_LIVE_API_USERNAME
- PAYPAL_LIVE_API_PASSWORD
- PAYPAL_LIVE_API_SECRET

I'm not getting any errors, I'm just being redirected back.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check whether you changed the mode  to live in the configuration file or not?